# pass date and time pattern to awk

Tags: bash, awk

Following command:

```
grep -a volume somefile | awk '/^Apr 25 23:44:04*/,/^Apr 26 12:44:01*/ {print}'
```

works perfectly fine but when I try to execute it by putting the date and time in a variable and execute it doesn't seem to work.

```
time1="Apr 25 23:44:04"

time2="Apr 26 12:44:01"

grep -a volume somefile | awk '/^"$time1"/,/^"$time2"/ {print}'
```

Comment: It isn't obvious why you have the stars in the regexes in the first example.  However, if the first matching record is `Apr 25 23:44:09` instead of `Apr 25 23:44:04`, then the first pair of regexes will match and the second won't.  Further, if the earliest record that is in the range is `Apr 25 23:44:10`, then nothing will be printed at all since the first regex never matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside single quotes, `$` has no significance.  You currently have:

```
grep -a volume somefile | awk '/^"$time1"/,/^"$time2"/ {print}'
```

That's looking for a line containing a double quote, a dollar sign, the letters t, i, m, e, digit 1, and another double quote — it probably doesn't find it.

You need:

```
grep -a volume somefile | awk '/^'"$time1"'/,/^'"$time2"'/ {print}'
```

or (more simply in this case, but less reliably in general):

```
grep -a volume somefile | awk "/^$time1/,/^$time2/ {print}"
```

Note that if the patterns being searched for contain slashes or backslashes, or other metacharacters, you will need to escape them.  If the patterns are simple date/time strings, as in this question, this works fine.

You have also lost the `*` in the regexes compared with the 'works perfectly' version.  This may or may not matter.

#### Example output

Given this script:

```
echo "Lines containing 'volume'"
echo
grep -a volume somefile

echo
echo "Version 1"
echo
grep -a volume somefile | awk '/^Apr 25 23:44:04*/,/^Apr 26 12:44:01*/ {print}' 

echo
echo "Version 2"
echo
time1="Apr 25 23:44:04"
time2="Apr 26 12:44:01"
grep -a volume somefile | awk "/^$time1/,/^$time2/ {print}"
```

I get the output:

```
Lines containing 'volume'

Apr 25 23:43:59 Record 234359 volume
Apr 25 23:44:00 Record 234400 volume
Apr 25 23:44:01 Record 234401 volume
Apr 25 23:44:02 Record 234402 volume
Apr 25 23:44:03 Record 234403 volume
Apr 25 23:44:04 Record 234404 volume
Apr 25 23:44:05 Record 234405 volume
Apr 25 23:44:06 Record 234406 volume
Apr 25 23:44:07 Record 234407 volume
Apr 25 23:44:08 Record 234408 volume
Apr 25 23:44:09 Record 234409 volume
Apr 25 23:44:10 Record 234410 volume
blank volume
Apr 26 00:00:00 Record 000000 volume
Apr 2009 Record 2009 volume
Apr 26 12:00:00 Record 120000 volume
blank volume
Apr 26 12:44:00 Record 124400 volume
Apr 26 12:44:01 Record 124401 volume
Apr 26 12:44:02 Record 124402 volume
Apr 26 12:44:03 Record 124403 volume
Apr 26 12:44:04 Record 124404 volume

Version 1

Apr 25 23:44:00 Record 234400 volume
Apr 25 23:44:01 Record 234401 volume
Apr 25 23:44:02 Record 234402 volume
Apr 25 23:44:03 Record 234403 volume
Apr 25 23:44:04 Record 234404 volume
Apr 25 23:44:05 Record 234405 volume
Apr 25 23:44:06 Record 234406 volume
Apr 25 23:44:07 Record 234407 volume
Apr 25 23:44:08 Record 234408 volume
Apr 25 23:44:09 Record 234409 volume
Apr 25 23:44:10 Record 234410 volume
blank volume
Apr 26 00:00:00 Record 000000 volume
Apr 2009 Record 2009 volume
Apr 26 12:00:00 Record 120000 volume
blank volume
Apr 26 12:44:00 Record 124400 volume

Version 2

Apr 25 23:44:04 Record 234404 volume
Apr 25 23:44:05 Record 234405 volume
Apr 25 23:44:06 Record 234406 volume
Apr 25 23:44:07 Record 234407 volume
Apr 25 23:44:08 Record 234408 volume
Apr 25 23:44:09 Record 234409 volume
Apr 25 23:44:10 Record 234410 volume
blank volume
Apr 26 00:00:00 Record 000000 volume
Apr 2009 Record 2009 volume
Apr 26 12:00:00 Record 120000 volume
blank volume
Apr 26 12:44:00 Record 124400 volume
Apr 26 12:44:01 Record 124401 volume
```

The "lines containing 'volume'" is effectively the data file that is being used.

The "Version 1" block shows that the `*` in the regex matter.

The "Version 2" block shows that with careful quoting, the dates can be made to work, but note that the output is different from "Version 1" because of the absence of stars.  Adding the stars back would give the same results as in "Version 1".

Comment: both cmds did not help. Here is the file from which I am trying to extract the log between "Apr 25 01:45:00" and "Apr 26 12:45:00":
#cat tempFile
Apr 24 10:47:00.6631 somedata
Apr 25 01:47:00.6631 somedata
Apr 25 12:47:00.6635 somedata
Apr 25 23:47:00.6667 somedata
Apr 26 12:47:00.3177 somedata
Apr 26 11:48:00.663177 somedata
Apr 26 23:47:00.377 somedata
May 11 23:47:00.177 somedata
Mar 11 23:47:00.177 somedata
#variables
time1="Apr 25 01:45:00"
time2="Apr 26 12:45:00"

#cat tempFile | sort -k1,1M -k2,2n -k3,3 |  awk '/^"$time1"/,/^"$time2"/ {print}'
>>>No output

Comment: Does the 'somedata' include the word 'volume'?  If not, the `grep` never selects anything, so the `awk` doesn't get a chance.

Comment: Don't use range expressions as they make trivial things very slightly briefer but everything else much harder, don't allow shell variables to expand to become part of the body of an awk script as they produce bizarre errors given the contents of those variables, and don't use double quotes to delimit awk scripts as they add complexity like making you escape `$` signs for field references and double escape backslashes. See @Jotne's answer for the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do it is make `awk` use indata as  variables.
Using Jonathans data as example.

```
grep -a volume somedata | awk -v start="$time1" -v end="$time2" '$0~start {f=1} f; $0~end {f=0}'
Apr 25 23:44:04 Record 234404 volume
Apr 25 23:44:05 Record 234405 volume
Apr 25 23:44:06 Record 234406 volume
Apr 25 23:44:07 Record 234407 volume
Apr 25 23:44:08 Record 234408 volume
Apr 25 23:44:09 Record 234409 volume
Apr 25 23:44:10 Record 234410 volume
blank volume
Apr 26 00:00:00 Record 000000 volume
Apr 2009 Record 2009 volume
Apr 26 12:00:00 Record 120000 volume
blank volume
Apr 26 12:44:00 Record 124400 volume
Apr 26 12:44:01 Record 124401 volume
```

---

To make sure data hits from start of the line.

```
grep -a volume somedata | awk -v start="$time1" -v end="$time2" 'BEGIN {start="^"start;end="^"end} $0~start {f=1} f; $0~end {f=0}'
```

Comment: Can you skip the grep with more code in awk or would that become unreadible?

Comment: @WalterA I am not very familiar with `-a, --text, equivalent to --binary-files=text ` in `grep` and how to do the same with `awk`

Comment: You might be able to set `BINMODE` in gawk but it's not something I've played with much either except to set `-v BINMODE=3` on cygwin to stop `\r`s getting stripped from the input before my script sees them.